# No more data to read from socket error using dblink - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I'm getting this error (No more data to read from socket) even when I try to do the simple query like:

```
SELECT 
T."ID" as user_id FROM "TEST"@DBLINK T where rownum<10
```

I already looked for more details in tracelog and got this:

`Thu Jul 02 11:23:46 2015
Archived Log entry 431583 added for thread 1 sequence 451623 ID 0x8ae0db51 dest 1:
Thu Jul 02 11:30:32 2015
HS:  Lost RPC connection to remote Agent...
HS:  ... Agent SID = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.173)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=cf))), NCR status = -2147385341
Exception [type: SIGSEGV, Address not mapped to object] [ADDR:0x7FFF351D7F40] [PC:0x20E0101, kxsffir()+193] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/bfdwbr/BFDWBR/trace/BFDWBR_ora_25533.trc  (incident=1197429):
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [kxsffir()+193] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x7FFF351D7F40] [PC:0x20E0101] [Address not mapped to object] []
ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID=ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.173)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=cf)))
ORA-02063: preceding line from CF
Incident details in: /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/bfdwbr/BFDWBR/incident/incdir_1197429/BFDWBR_ora_25533_i1197429.trc
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.`

Anyone there is any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you gut an ORA-600 or 7445 you should look them up on My Oracle Support using the "ORA-600 tool".  Although in this case, the resulting document, "ORA-7445 [kxsffir] (Doc ID 310469.1)", doesn't seem to help much.  You'll probably need to create a Service Request with Oracle.  It might also help to mention the exact operating system and version of both the source and the target database.  These problems can be extremely specific.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like an intermittent network connectivity issue.  The phrase "lost RPC connection" is a good indication. You should also look in the trace file mentioned.

As a test you can make a script, something like

```
DECLARE
  V_NUMBER NUMBER(9);
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1 .. .500 LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT T."ID" AS USER_ID
        INTO V_NUMBER
        FROM "TEST"@DBLINK T
       WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('time is ' || SYSDATE || 'User id is ' ||
                           V_NUMBER);
    END LOOP;

  END;
```

This should give you an idea of when the interruption happens or if it is consistent.